# Recorrer registros en cada celda con PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

vengo a pedirles su ayuda para saber como puedo recorrer mis registros en cada celda según la condición de si se cumple la fecha.

Estoy creando un sistema de asistencias, donde en mi BD, guardo 2 campos, (fecha y hora), donde manejo 3 condiciones

1. 08:00 a 08:15 (sin Retardo).
2. 08:16 a 08:30 (Restado).
3. 08:31 en adelante (Falta).

Todo eso, genero un reporte en Excel con PhpSpreadsheet, asi como este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi Reporte, manejo los días del mes (M1 = Martes 1, M2 = Miercoles 2, Etc.), lo que intento hacer es que si un registro cumple la condición por ejemplo de que si checa 08:20 en la fecha que registro se Ponga una **R**.

Mi consulta **Mysql** para extraer los datos es la siguiente

```html
SELECT
        p.nombre,
        p.primer_apellido,
        p.segundo_apellido,
        GROUP_CONCAT( a.`hour` ) AS hours,
        GROUP_CONCAT( a.`date` ) AS dates,
        c.nombre AS dir 
    FROM
        asistencias.attendance a
        INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
        INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
    WHERE
        MONTH ( a.`date` ) = 11 
    GROUP BY
        p.id,
        p.nombre,
        p.primer_apellido,
        p.segundo_apellido,
        c.nombre
```

**El cual me muestra los siguientes datos.**

```
LAURA VAZQUEZ   08:04:10,07:47:52,07:53:55 2022-11-17,2022-11-18,2022-11-22 Tic´s

ARTURO  PEREZ 07:50:49,07:51:10,07:49:31    2022-11-17,2022-11-18,2022-11-22    Diseño y Modas
```

El problema que tengo es que intento hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```html
if ($row['dates'] == "2022-11-01") {
                if ($row['hours'] <= '08:15:59') {
                    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E'.$i , "")->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(8);
                }elseif ($row['hours'] === '08:16:00' || $row['hours'] <= '08:30:59') {
                    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E'.$i , "R")->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(8);
                }elseif ($row['hours'] > '08:31:00') {
                    $activeSheet->setCellValue('E'.$i , "F")->getColumnDimension('E')->setWidth(8);
                }
            }
```

Sin embargo no lo hace porque mis campos **(dates y hours)** CONCATENAN los registros y mis condiciones no las acepta, no se si alguien pueda ayudarme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con los datos que tienes, puedes separarlos inicialmente, para posteriormente procesarlos en un for, y realizas los if. Eso seria en php, pero recomendaria que desde el sql realizaras un case para devolver como tal los datos que necesitas, o el texto de retardo etc

```
$dates = explode(",", $row['dates']);
$hours = explode(",", $row['hours']);

for (i=0; i<count($dates); i++) {
    if ($dates[i] == "2022-11-01"){
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu código se puede optimizar desde la raíz, creando en la tabla una sola columna que sea del tipo `DATETIME`, eso te permitirá guardar las dos informaciones (fecha y hora) en un solo sitio, ahorrando espacio, ganando en rendimiento y en simplicidad.

Otra ventaja es que, una vez tengas tu objeto completo, lo podrás desgajar para trabajar con otras cosas, como obtener el día de la semana, hacer otro cálculos, etc, partiendo siempre del mismo objeto.

Vamos a hacerlo a mano, uniendo la fecha y la hora en una sola columna.

```
SELECT
        p.nombre,
        p.primer_apellido,
        p.segundo_apellido,
        GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT(a.`date`, ' ', a.`hour`) ) AS dates,
        c.nombre AS dir 
    FROM
        asistencias.attendance a
        INNER JOIN personal.personal p ON a.employee_id = p.id
        INNER JOIN personal.ads_personal ad ON p.id = ad.idPersonal
        INNER JOIN personal.catdireccion c ON ad.idDireccion = c.id 
    WHERE
        MONTH ( a.`date` ) = 11 
    GROUP BY
        p.id,
        p.nombre,
        p.primer_apellido,
        p.segundo_apellido,
        c.nombre
```

Ahora tus datos vendrán así:

```
LAURA VAZQUEZ   2022-11-17 08:04:10,2022-11-18 07:47:52,2022-11-22 07:53:55     Tic´s

ARTURO  PEREZ   2022-11-17 07:50:49,2022-11-18 07:51:10,2022-11-22 07:49:31     Diseño y Modas
```

Tendrás las fechas y las horas juntas y el código será más fácil. Vamos a aplicarlo en PHP:

```
$dates=explode(",",$row['dates']);
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $dateTime=new DateTime($date);
    if( $dateTime->format('H:i:s')>='08:00:00' && $dateTime->format('H:i:s')<='08:15:59'){
        //Sin retardo
    }  
    if( $dateTime->format('H:i:s')>='08:16:00' && $dateTime->format('H:i:s')<='08:30:59'){
        //Restado
    }            
    if($dateTime->format('H:i:s')>='08:31'){
        //Falta
    }
}
```

Aquí `$dateTime` será un objeto `DateTime` con cada fecha y hora.

---

Otro forma de resolver esto, sería partiendo de la misma consulta SQL, usando [`CASE ... WHEN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html).

En el código, asumiremos que tu columna `hour` es del tipo `TIME()` (si fuese de tipo `VARCHAR()` también funcionaría, asumiendo que declarar tipos equivocados abre la puerta a datos equivocados en muchos casos), y en los `CASE` asignaremos a una columna con alias `status` las letras: `S` para *sin retardo*, `R` para *restado*  y `F` para *falta* y si ninguno de los casos se cumple, asignamos `NA` (no aplica).

El código quedaría así:

```
SELECT ...
    CASE 
        WHEN a.`hour` BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:15:59' THEN 'S'
        WHEN a.`hour` BETWEEN '08:16:00' AND '08:30:59' THEN 'R'
        WHEN a.`hour` >= '08:31:00' THEN 'F'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS `status`
FROM ...
```

Aquí tienes un fiddle sobre el cual puedes hacer pruebas:

**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  `id` INT,
  `hour` TIME
);
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (1,'08:00:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (2,'08:01:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (3,'08:15:59');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (4,'08:16:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (5,'08:17:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (6,'08:30:59');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (7,'08:31:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (8,'08:32:00');
INSERT INTO test (`id`,`hour`) VALUES (9,'06:00:00');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT 
    `hour`,
    CASE 
        WHEN `hour` BETWEEN '08:00:00' AND '08:15:59' THEN 'S'
        WHEN `hour` BETWEEN '08:16:00' AND '08:30:59' THEN 'R'
        WHEN `hour` >= '08:31:00' THEN 'F'
        ELSE 'NA'
    END AS `status`
FROM test;
```

| hour | status |
| --- | --- |
| 08:00:00 | S |
| 08:01:00 | S |
| 08:15:59 | S |
| 08:16:00 | R |
| 08:17:00 | R |
| 08:30:59 | R |
| 08:31:00 | F |
| 08:32:00 | F |
| 06:00:00 | NA |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uTBPTugiWFSeXz5r6hxmhW/2)